# Layout issue. Have issues with using tables

Tags: android, xml

I wanted to do something like 3 big columns to separate 3 activities. But I'm not sure how do I split the second column where I wanna put a map in it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!----- 1 main table to split into 3 columns ------>
    <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!----- 1 row ------>
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >
            <!-----@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@- Column 1 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@------>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/connect_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:text="Connect" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/disconnect_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:text="Disconnect" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="207dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFF00"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/s1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:text="S1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/s2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:text="S2" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/configure"
                    android:layout_width="81dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="openConfigurations"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Gallery
                        android:id="@+id/gallery2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/up"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:src="@drawable/up" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/left"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/left" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/toggle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/check"
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn="" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/right"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:src="@drawable/right" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/down"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:src="@drawable/down" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
    </TableLayout>


                    <!-----@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@- Column 2 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@------>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_row="9"
            android:background="#FFFFAA" >

        <com.example.project.image_map
            android:id="@+id/mapView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

     </RelativeLayout>

                <!-----@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@- Column 3 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@------>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" 
            android:layout_column="3"/>

    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure because I tried to put the "android:layout_column="2" in the relative layout and there is an error. How should I define which activity to be in which column? It is not like an image or button where I just simple add in the layout_column..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by  3 big columns to separate 3 activities.?

Answer (score 1):

In RelativeLayout your UI components position are relative to other UI components and the parent container. You cannot use android:layout_column in RelativeLayout. You can define any activity for any column as long as you add a reference to it in your java activity class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. There're different things you might want to do.

First, here's how your Layout looks like in landscape orinetation:
[image: current layout/landscape]

Then the question is, what is wrong with it? How do you want it to look like? I can assume a few things, but it needs a bit more guidance.

- In portrait orientation there's not enough space to show such a complex screen. You can set in the manifest, that this Activity should only be shown in landscape mode and should not change orientation, no matter what the user does. The way to set this in the manifest: `<activity android:name="+yourActivityClass+" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>`
- Maybe you want to split the three areas into three different screens with the possibility to switch between them e.g. by wiping left to right and back. In this case you better use Fragments. In Eclipse, when you create a new Activity, it asks you about the kind of navigation you want and creates a skeleton.